# Google Action Deployed but not invoked

Tags: actions-on-google

I got an approval email from google that my action is approved. When I go to google action console, I see that the status as "Deployed", which means that it should be available to all other users. I have deployed the release in the production mode, not alpha or beta. When I invoke the action using my account on Assistant, it says that using test version. If I use assistant using other accounts, the action doesn't even get recognized. Any help in this regards will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, action deployment can take a while (1-3 days). However, you can check the country and language settings in the mean time and be sure everything is right. I think, it will be deployed soon.